# how to show a "window/subactivity/dialog" on top of an Activity but keeping the focus in the Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, subactivity

My activity A is a game and it does some background operations. When I press a button in the contextual menu, I want to pop up a "small window/dialog/subactivity" (lets call it B) that appears on top of activity A and displays some data about those background operations. But I need to keep the focus on the activity A in order to continue interacting with it (playing the game).

In essence, I want to be able to see the data display by B while playing the game.

I'm not really sure how to implement this. After reading the documentation I have the next conclusions:

- I know that I can't use Dialogs because the have the focus. Is it possible to avoid this?
- Using a subactivity with a Dialog theme it's another option that looks tempting...but I believe that the subactivity has the focus. Ditto.
- My last option is to try to add a LinearLayout with my data to the main Layout, "sharing/splitting" the screen. It's not pretty, but at least I know that this is possible. What I don't like about this approach is that I use the  width and height of the screen.

Any suggestions? Solutions?

PS: I found some this thread here that are very related to my question:

- [Android ==> Sub Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367869/android-sub-activity)

Comment: How much information are you talking about for B?  If B can be passive, why don't you use a Toast?

Comment: I thought about that, but TOASTs disappear after X time. Besides, I want to see how my info changes in real time and I don't think you can do that with Toasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Activity with style `Theme.Dialog`. This is a normal activity which looks like a dialog, while being modeless and accepting events.

Additional catch is in setting `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` and resetting `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND`.

See this answer for complete example: [timed modeless dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132699/timed-modeless-dialog/4133245#4133245)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it. Quick question: Do you know if the onPause() method of the main activity invoked when using this approach? This is crucial also... Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the onPause() method would be invoked here. It would be easy to test though. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a FrameLayout that is apart of your Activity? Just ensure that this View has a higher z index (make sure you declare it last in your XML layout or create it at runtime). That way you never leave your Activity.